Lora and data rate in IoT
Lora uses spread spectrum modulation with chirps. To get the same data rate, why don't we use DSSS with QAM modulation for example?

Wow, you're essentially asking "why was LoRa designed the way it was?", and that's an extremely broad question; aside from technical aspects of transmission and reception, there's regulatory questions, questions of technical implementability in cheap ICs, directly coupled to very important questions of intellectual property, which probably dictated core parts of the technological stack.
That being said, compared to classical DSSS, the spreading with chirp circular position modulation is elegant because the ML detector for the amount the chirp was circularly shifted in time is effectively a slightly modified FFT, which is computationally super elegant, and can be implemented very power-efficiently.
The assumption that you can do anything larger than 4-QAM on a spread-spectrum signal might assume more SNR than would typically available in a low-power wide area network. You simply can't blow 5W into the air, even for a short time, if you need to keep your battery for long, and if you're using ISM or unlicensed bands, or don't want to foster a contention problem.

LoRa PHY uses Chirp Spread Spectrum (CSS) that provides a constant envelope signal, crucial for efficient power amplifier operation. This means simpler and cheaper amplifier.
Check also this website Understanding LoRa PHY (Long-Range Physical Layer).
